# Change layout from the drawer activity example

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've created a new project, starting with the "Navigation drawer activity" set by default. I wanted to change the layout when a button of the navigation drawer is pressed.

In the MainActivity.java, I added the last line here:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            setContentView(R.layout.app_bar_main2);
        ...
```

I've also created a new layout named app_bar_main2, and added a basic TextView.

I've not done anything else (which might be why it's not working), and when I run the app and click on the gallery icon, the app closes itself.

What have I to do to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to android!  Are you familiar with Android fragments? Fragments allow you to easily do this.

Comment: Use Fragments instead of setContentView line... It works well.. Do you want to use activity there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on any option in the `Navigation Drawer Activity` in Android, it opens a fragment on the main UI and closes the earlier fragment by itself.

All you need to do is make a Fragment visible on the UI on the selection of an option

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) some help about Fragments